# EROR: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Tags: python

I write this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1= fig.add_subplot(111)

sns.lineplot(x=dataset["Time"],y=dataset["Value"], data=df)
plt.title("Energy Consumption vs Time ")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.grid(True, alpha=1)
plt.legend()

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)
```

But this error message appears:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: what line does throw the error ? share the full stackteac

Comment: include the complete error/traceback in the post

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-130919db4b67> in <module>
      2 ax1= fig.add_subplot(111)
      3 
----> 4 sns.lineplot(x=dataset["Time"],y=dataset["Value"], data=df)
      5 plt.title("Energy Consumption vs Time ")
      6 plt.xlabel("Time")

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'